# How to reduce gap between 2 different items of a recyclerView?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

[image]

See this gap between the `textViews` of different items

There is a lot of spacing between the 2 different items in my recyclerView....Here is my xml Code...When I add every element like recycler View and textView and progressBar in a Linear layout then everything sticks to left top of the screen....please help

```
    `enter code here`
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D500F9"
    tools:context=".Dogs_Diseases">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    `android:layout_width="414dp"
    android:layout_height="652dp"
    android:background="#FBF7F7"
    android:elevation="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="219dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:shadowColor="#D14141"
    android:text="Dogs"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#00E5FF"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.453"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.009" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#751C1C"
    android:backgroundTint="#CC2121"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.922"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the xml layout of one item of the recycler view. I.e. what you're inflating in your adapter. I'm assuming in it, you will want to change your `layout_height` to `wrap_content` rather than `match_parent`, this is a common mistake, but I can't be sure without the layout itself.

Comment: Please post your recyclerview item xml layout

Comment: thank you bro @Vucko....It was quite a common but I also did the same